# How to uncompressed output in jade?

Tags: node.js, html, pug

Well the default output of jade is compressed or minified version of HTML. So how to make the output unminified version via terminal while watching?

Answer (score 0):

[Pug's CLI interface](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli)

```
-P, --pretty           compile pretty HTML output
```

Comment: You got the point now I got the correct answer to my own question!

Answer (score 0):

For watching your jade via terminal with uncompressed output via terminal is by using this commands.

```
jade -w -P index.jade
```

Explains:
-w, --watch = this is to watch your changes
-P, --pretty = this is to uncompress your output rendered html

Thanks for all who tried to answer this question this is help to the guys who use jade via terminal.